# Linq query returning duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

So I have two DataTables, both taken from the same ODBC data source. One has rows for sales (Estado='VENTAS') and another for Estado='EXIST' (the database creates row pairs for each sale, one indicates the sale information and the other the information about stock movements off the store's deposit, so in order to know what store made a sale, I have to match each VENTAS row to the corresponding EXIST row [by the 'Documento' ID field] and get the "Deposito" value off the Exist row).

I built this query to do that (the ODBC driver I'm using doesn't allow for joins so doing it in Linq was the next best thing)

```
            DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

            dtResult.Columns.Add("Documento", typeof(Int64)); 
            dtResult.Columns.Add("Fecha", typeof(DateTime));
            dtResult.Columns.Add("Articulo", typeof(string));
            dtResult.Columns.Add("Deposito", typeof(string));
            dtResult.Columns.Add("ImpDMn", typeof(decimal));
            dtResult.Columns.Add("Cantidad", typeof(decimal));
            dtResult.Columns.Add("Partida", typeof(string));

            var result = from dataRows1 in VentasDT.AsEnumerable() //VentasDT is the DataTable with the VENTAS data
                         join dataRows2 in ExistDT.AsEnumerable() // ExistDT is the DataTable with the EXIST data
                         on dataRows1.Field<Int64>("Documento") equals dataRows2.Field<Int64>("Documento")
                         select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
         {
            dataRows1.Field<Int64>("Documento"),
            dataRows1.Field<DateTime>("Fecha"),
            dataRows1.Field<string>("Articulo"),
            dataRows2.Field<string>("Deposito"),
            dataRows1.Field<decimal>("ImpDMn"),
            dataRows1.Field<decimal>("Cantidad"),
            dataRows1.Field<string>("Partida"),
          }, false);
            result.CopyToDataTable();
```

and it works but for some reason it duplicates *some* rows. 
I checked the rows that were duplicated and they are identical to each other. Their Document numbers are equal (and there is only one VENTAS and one EXIST row per Documento number, including for these duplicates) so I don't know why they're getting duplicated. I checked on the source Datatables I'm joining and likewise, there is only one corresponding line in each for the duplicates. The EXIST table is larger than the VENTAS table (it also records transfers between stores that aren't sales) but the joined table is larger than either (yet not as large as both combined)

```
VENTAS: 85123
EXIST: 116857
JOIN: 141287
```

Is there something wrong with my query? Should I include some GROUP BY clause or .Distinct or should this structure (which as far as I've seen should mimic a left join) have been enough?

Comment: Can records representing transfers in the `EXIST` table have their `Documento` field be equal to the `Documento` field from `VENTAS`?

Comment: No. Transfers have their own unique Documento value for which no reciprocal would be found in the Ventas table and as far as I've seen, every duplicate in the join table has a Documento value that shows up in the original Ventas table (hence not a transfer)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only reason that you are doing this join is to get the value of the `"Deposito"` fields from `ExistDT`, you can replace joining with a dictionary lookup. Here is how you can do it:

```
var depositoPorDocumento = ExistDT.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(
    dr => dr.Field<Int64>("Documento"),
    dr => dr.Field<string>("Deposito")
);
foreach (var vr in VentasDT.AsEnumerable()) {
    Int64 id = Field<Int64>("Documento");
    string deposito;
    if (!depositoPorDocumento.TryGetValue(id, out deposito)) {
        continue;
    }
    dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
     {
        id,
        vr.Field<DateTime>("Fecha"),
        vr.Field<string>("Articulo"),
        deposito,
        vr.Field<decimal>("ImpDMn"),
        vr.Field<decimal>("Cantidad"),
        vr.Field<string>("Partida"),
      }, false);
}
result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Your solution is giving me many syntax errors: No definition and no extension method for (...) on ExistTD.ToDictionary();  foreach statement cannot operate on Datatable (...) on foreach (var vr in VentasDT;  and invalid arguments on !depositoPorDocumento.TryGetValue(id, out deposito) ...?

Comment: @ConnorU I wasn't sure what were `VentasDT` and `ExistTD`, so I skipped the `.AsEnumerable()` calls. I added them back, see if this compiles.

Comment: Your solution compiles but it crashes - which has shown me where I've been making my mistake: Each Documento may contain more than one line if more than one item was sold. I ordered my tables by Articulo ID and then by Document so they never seemed to be more than one and when I did the join, the program replaced every line with the first Articulo information it found, so it seemed to be a duplicate but it was a replacement...
Thanks for your answer, My question was wrong I need to edit it now

Comment: @ConnorU Did it crash in `ToDictionary`?

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple lines with the same Documento - the primary key would be a composite of Documento and Articulo id values, I did not realize that before